# How can i execute a python script in /etc/cron.hourly?

Tags: python, automation, cron

I always write shell scripts in lunux if i want them to be run automatically in /etc/cron.hourly. I have the following python script (designed for python 3.6, but default python version on my server is 2) that i would like to be executed in /etc/cron.hourly and not crontab. How can i achieve this?

```
"Perform automated database backups using xtrabackup"

import os

location='/opt/mysql/backups/daily'
with open('/authentication/account.txt') as f:
    mylist = f.read().splitlines()

username = mylist[0]
password = mylist[1]
hostname = mylist[2]

os.system(f"innobackupex --user={username} --password={password} -- 
host=localhost {location} >/dev/null 2>&1")

# Delete backup folders older than 3 days
os.system(f"find {location} -type d -ctime +7 | xargs rm -rf")
```

If this is possible, how can i ensure that cron.hourly is using python3.6 once i install this version instead of the default python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new shell script and place it in `/etc/cron.hourly` folder.

Shell script should look like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

python3.6 complete_path_of_your_script.py
```

The `python3.6` command makes sure that your script runs with 3.6 version (if **python 3.6** is already installed in your server)

For your reference - https://askubuntu.com/questions/7676/function-of-etc-cron-hourly

Comment: or put `#!/usr/bin/env python`at first of your python script and make sure that python is in your PATH